# How to determine the OS path separator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, directory

How can I tell in JavaScript what path separator is used in the OS where the script is running?

Comment: Why do you need this when Javascript is run inside the browser with complete OS isolation? You can't access files from your local computer...

Comment: JavaScript is usually, but not always, run in the browser. Some examples of JavaScript uses outside the browser are Mozilla XULRunner apps, js scripts run using a command-line interpreter like V8 or WSH, and ASP pages written in JScript. There are many uses for JS.

Comment: I'm sure you've already solved the issue, but I've added a use case for your question and an answer below, because like you, I know there's always a case where you can't depend on the OS to resolve the separator for you! :). Cheers!

Comment: This question is very relevant because JavaScript is often run inside Node.js. There you can and want to access the file-system so the path-separator matters.  This is also one of the pain-points if you want to create multi-OS Node.js applications. Node.js is multi-platform but that does not mean that any Node.js program runs on all supported OSes, without you paying special attention to the file-paths you use.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Afair you can always use / as a path separator, even on Windows.

Quote from http://bytes.com/forum/thread23123.html:

> So, the situation can be summed up
>   rather simply:
>
> - All DOS services since DOS 2.0 and all Windows APIs accept either forward
>     slash or backslash. Always have.
> - None of the standard command shells (CMD or COMMAND) will accept forward
>     slashes. Even the "cd ./tmp" example
>     given in a previous post fails.

Comment: VVS's answer is correct, with the exception of parsing a path given by a file input in internet explorer (tested with IE8 - I do not know about other versions). In this case, the path given by the input element's value (input.value) is in the form "C:\fakepath\&lt;filename&gt;". Note the backslashes here.

Comment: JFYI: cmd.exe handles "cd /windows" (as an example) correctly on both Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: This is not a fully CORRECT answer to the posed question... see "The Correct Answer" Below :).

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it ignores the perfect validity of the question- namely that there are cases where you actually need to know the path separator being used. For instance, needing to split a path into pieces would use the separator.

Comment: @VVS - Does not work in scenarios where you use both types of slashes (at least on Windows 7).  Consider the case where you are constructing a variable using __dirname and then you need to append the rest of the path. For example: __dirname + '/images'. In that example  __dirname will use the OS specific slashes, but if you try to use /images and you're on Windows, you will end up with a path like c:\somepath/images, and that won't work on Windows.  I just ran into this case, which is why I mention it :).

Comment: Does not work consistently across browsers when accessing `input type="file"`, which now often reports `C:\fakepath` prefix. Thus, backslashes instead of foreslashes. So, if you were parsing that for instance to get basename using `split`, you wouldn't get what you wanted.

Answer (score 227):

Use [`path`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html) module in `node.js` returns the platform-specific file separator. 
example

```
path.sep  // on *nix evaluates to a string equal to "/"
```

Edit: As per Sebas's comment below, to use this, you need to add this at the top of your js file:

```
const path = require('path')
```

Comment: You could improve your answer [specifying how: `path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_sep).

Comment: `const path = require('path');`

Comment: Though I know I can use '/' in most if not all of my cases. When I print output to the console for feedback or logging. I like to use the same slashes in a full path.

Comment: I think above is the correct answer and also the simplest solution.  As pointed out by Sebas to get access to the path-module you must do  path = require('path'). If you're a Node.programmer, even novice, you probably already know that.

Answer (score 17):

## The Correct Answer

**Yes** all OS's accept CD ../ or CD ..\  or CD .. regardless of how you pass in separators. But what about reading a path back. How would you know if its say, a 'windows' path, with `' '` and `\` allowed.

## The Obvious 'Duh!' Question

What happens when you depend on, for example, the installation directory `%PROGRAM_FILES% (x86)\Notepad++`. Take the following example.

```
var fs = require('fs');                             // file system module
var targetDir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++'; // target installer dir

// read all files in the directory
fs.readdir(targetDir, function(err, files) {

    if(!err){
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i){
            var currFile = files[i];

            console.log(currFile); 
            // ex output: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'

            // attempt to print the parent directory of currFile
            var fileDir = getDir(currFile);

            console.log(fileDir);  
            // output is empty string, ''...what!?
        }
    }
});

function getDir(filePath){
    if(filePath !== '' && filePath != null){

       // this will fail on Windows, and work on Others
       return filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    }
}
```

#### What happened!?

`targetDir` is being set to a substring between the indices `0`, and `0` (`indexOf('/')` is `-1` in `C:\Program Files\Notepad\Notepad++.exe`), resulting in the empty string.

## The Solution...

This includes code from the following post: [How do I determine the current operating system with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683895/how-do-i-determine-the-current-operating-system-with-node-js)

```
myGlobals = { isWin: false, isOsX:false, isNix:false };
```

Server side detection of OS.

```
// this var could likely a global or available to all parts of your app
if(/^win/.test(process.platform))     { myGlobals.isWin=true; }
else if(process.platform === 'darwin'){ myGlobals.isOsX=true; }
else if(process.platform === 'linux') { myGlobals.isNix=true; }
```

Browser side detection of OS

```
var appVer = navigator.appVersion;
if      (appVer.indexOf("Win")!=-1)   myGlobals.isWin = true;
else if (appVer.indexOf("Mac")!=-1)   myGlobals.isOsX = true;
else if (appVer.indexOf("X11")!=-1)   myGlobals.isNix = true;
else if (appVer.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) myGlobals.isNix = true;
```

Helper Function to get the separator

```
function getPathSeparator(){
    if(myGlobals.isWin){
        return '\\';
    }
    else if(myGlobals.isOsx  || myGlobals.isNix){
        return '/';
    }

    // default to *nix system.
    return '/';
}

// modifying our getDir method from above...
```

Helper function to get the parent directory (cross platform)

```
function getDir(filePath){
    if(filePath !== '' && filePath != null){
       // this will fail on Windows, and work on Others
       return filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf(getPathSeparator()) + 1);
    }
}
```

`getDir()` must be intelligent enough to know which its looking for.

You can get even really slick and check for both if the user is inputting a path via command line, etc.

```
// in the body of getDir() ...
var sepIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf('/');
if(sepIndex == -1){
    sepIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf('\\');
}

// include the trailing separator
return filePath.substring(0, sepIndex+1);
```

You can also use 'path' module and path.sep as stated above, if you want to load a module to do this simple of a task. Personally, i think it sufficient to just check the information from the process that is already available to you.

```
var path = require('path');
var fileSep = path.sep;    // returns '\\' on windows, '/' on *nix
```

### And Thats All Folks!

Comment: I like that you presented logic for finding the separator to use, breaking it into manageable chunks. This is how a professional works as an engineer. **+1** for that. Also, considering the age of the question and the lack of a `NodeJS` tag - you've answered for both *server* and *client* side. Your answer does fully - and *actually* - answer the question.  For node, I think the path module is fine because it will not impact generated bytecode performance and should not impact readability (a single import statement). You're the only answer to client-side, however. This should be the accepted.

Answer (score 10):

As already answered here, you can find the OS specific path separator with `path.sep` to manually construct your path. But you can also let `path.join` do the job, which is my preferred solution when dealing with path constructions:

**Example:**

```
const path = require('path');

const directory = 'logs';
const file = 'data.json';

const path1 = `${directory}${path.sep}${file}`;
const path2 = path.join(directory, file);

console.log(path1); // Shows "logs\data.json" on Windows
console.log(path2); // Also shows "logs\data.json" on Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can get this information from `window.navigator.userAgent`