# How to determine the OS path separator in JavaScript (2)?

Tags: javascript, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the OS path separator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125813/how-to-determine-the-os-path-separator-in-javascript)

I am looking for the JavaScript constant that is equivalent to Java's: File.separator

couldn't find the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125813/how-to-determine-the-os-path-separator-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the OS path separator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125813/how-to-determine-the-os-path-separator-in-javascript). Rather than posting a duplicate, you should add a comment and a bounty to the other question.

Comment: @Andy E the task is different, so it's not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: @Eugene: yet the marked accepted answer is pretty much the same as the one in the other question.

Comment: @Andy the answer also has comments and I assume it was actually a comment that was accepted.

Comment: @Eugene: there's no way of knowing for sure and besides, comments *aren't answers*. Feel free to read [The Wikipedia of long-tail programming questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What didn't you like in the accepted answer of the referenced question? You can always use forwrd slash. cmd.exe accepts "cd /temp" correctly, I have just checked this on Windows XP SP2 and on Windows 7.

Comment: This doesn't help me because I need to parse the content of input file element. I need to know how the OS will create the String- with '/' or with '\' , my page should work both on windows and Linux.

Comment: @Spiderman depending on your exact task you can analyze if input string has "[a-z]:" or "\\" as first characters. If yes, then this is a Windows absolute path (either DOS path or UNC path).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no constant you will have to discover the platform and set according.