# How can I write a Gruntfile with different shell command behaviour for OS X vs. Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, gruntjs

I have a Gruntfile which I intend to use on both OS X and Linux (Ubuntu, to be precise). I have some logic wrapped up inside [a grunt-shell task](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell):

```
shell: {
  somejob_linux: {
    command: [
      'firstlinuxcommand',
      'secondlinuxcommand'
    ]
  },
  somejob_osx: {
    command: [
      'firstosxcommand',
      'secondosxcommand'
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to have the first target (`somejob_linux`) executed if the Gruntfile is being run on Linux, and `somejob_osx` for OS X.

Is there an elegant way for me to achieve this? Or is there another alternative for having different commands or Grunt task/targets run for each platform? I'd prefer to keep everything within the Gruntfile, rather than calling out to external scripts simply for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this in only config, but you could create a custom task to [check the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683895/variable-to-detect-operating-system-in-node-scripts) and then add the appropriate task to the queue:

```
grunt.registerTask('detectthenrun', 'Detect the environment, then run a task', function() {
    if (/linux/.test(process.platform)) {
        grunt.task.run( 'somejob_linux' );
    } else if (/darwin/.test(process.platform)) {
        grunt.task.run( 'somejob_osx' );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Worth pointing out that it looks like process.platform actually returns `darwin` on OS X. I've corrected your answer.

Comment: The edit was rejected as it "looks" like you were editing to muck with the original intent. :) I'll correct this as you suggest... please accept if it solves your problem!