# open a file with default program in node-webkit

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, node.js, node-webkit

I want to give the user any option he want to edit a file, how can I open a file with the default program of the specific file type? I need it to work with Windows and Linux but Mac option would be great too.

Comment: can you explain more ? your question isn't that clear

Comment: I have a file path, I want to open it with the default program

Answer (score 22, accepted):

as PSkocik said, first detect the platform and get the command line :

```
function getCommandLine() {
   switch (process.platform) { 
      case 'darwin' : return 'open';
      case 'win32' : return 'start';
      case 'win64' : return 'start';
      default : return 'xdg-open';
   }
}
```

second , execute the command line followed by the path

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec(getCommandLine() + ' ' + filePath);
```

Comment: Can we get a closed signal ? Is there a call back where I would know application was closed ?

Comment: DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead. Maybe switch to? var sys = require('util');

Comment: @KimT Thanks for letting us know. I think we can remove `var sys = require('sys');` it's not being used. I have no idea why I included it in the solution. I will update the answer now.

Comment: There's also no need for `case: 'win64'` as process.platform is "win32", even on 64-bit versions of Windows ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684009/2950509))

Comment: Does anyone know about any problems with opening .docm files with this command? Whenever I try to open a docm file I get an error that it's being used by another program. But if I go to a file location and double click on it.. it opens fine.

Comment: Do not use this filePath could be `"; rm -rf /"`

Comment: No "win64" in process.platform https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processplatform

Comment: does not work if my filePath has spaces in it

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) module:

```
npm install --save open
```

and then call it in your Node.js file:

```js
const open = require('open');
open('my-file.txt');
```

This module already contains the logic to detect the operating system and it runs the default program that is associated to this file type by your system.

Comment: Very easy to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For file on a disk:

```
var nwGui = require('nw.gui');
nwGui.Shell.openItem("/path/to/my/file");
```

For remote files (eg web page):

```
var nwGui = require('nw.gui');
nwGui.Shell.openExternal("http://google.com/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Detect the platform and use:

- 'start' on Windows
- 'open' on Macs
- 'xdg-open' on Linux

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if start used to work as is on earlier windows versions, however on windows 10 it doesn't work as indicated in the answer. It's first argument is the title of the window.

Furthermore the behavior between windows and linux is different. Windows "start" will exec and exit, under linux, xdg-open will wait.

This was the function that eventually worked for me on both platforms in a similar manner:

```
  function getCommandLine() {
     switch(process.platform) {
       case 'darwin' :
         return 'open';
       default:
         return 'xdg-open';
     }
  }

  function openFileWithDefaultApp(file) {
       /^win/.test(process.platform) ? 
           require("child_process").exec('start "" "' + file + '"') :
           require("child_process").spawn(getCommandLine(), [file],
                {detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'}).unref(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aim to script some kind of prompt with a default editor or simply chain files opening, you will have to wait until the program ends or fail.

Inspired from [PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902347/open-a-file-with-default-program-in-node-webkit/29905280#29905280) and [Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902347/open-a-file-with-default-program-in-node-webkit/29917107#29917107) answers.

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');

let openFile=function(filePath,mute){

    let command=(function() {
        switch (process.platform) { 
            case 'darwin' : return 'open '+filePath+' && lsof -p $! +r 1 &>/dev/null';
            case 'win32' : 
            case 'win64' : return 'start /wait '+filePath;
            default : return 'xdg-open '+filePath+' && tail --pid=$! -f /dev/null';
        }
    })();

    
    if(!mute)console.log(command);
    let child=exec(command);
    if(!mute)child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    
    return new function(){
        this.on=function(type,callback){
            if(type==='data')child.stdout.on('data',callback);
            else if(type==='error')child.stderr.on('data',callback);
            else child.on('exit',callback);
            return this;
        };
        this.toPromise=function(){
            return new Promise((then,fail)=>{
                let out=[];
                this.on('data',d=>out.push(d))
                .on('error',err=>fail(err))
                .on('exit',()=>then(out));
            });
        };
    }();
};
```

use :

```
openFile('path/to/some_text.txt')
.on('data',data=>{
    console.log('output :'+data);
})
.on('error',err=>{
    console.log('error :'+err);
})
.on('exit',()=>{
    console.log('done');
});
```

or :

```
openFile('path/to/some_text.txt').toPromise()
.then(output=>{
    console.log('done output :'+output.join('\n'));
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('error :'+err);
});
```

PS : Let me know if it waits for other sytems than winXX ( Inspired from [Rauno Palosaari post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-a-process-to-finish/41613532#41613532) but not tested yet ).