# Open external file with OS' default application (docx with Word, etc.) using NodeJS and Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm using NodeJS/Electron for a desktop app.

What I wanna do, is to open a file with it's OS' default application, like .docx with Word.

What I tried so far are approaches using child_process.spawn, .exec or .execFile but I don't get anything.

Here is my actual code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    cp = require('child_process');

cp.spawn(__dirname + '/test.docx');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29917107/5334137

Comment: I arrived here and missed the question was Electron-specific. The accepted solution will only work inside an Electron app. There is a separate question for Node.js in general, outside of an Electron app: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8500326/62269

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [`openItem()`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.10/docs/api/shell.md#shellopenitemfullpath) function provided by Electron's `shell` module, for example:

```
const shell = require('electron').shell;
const path = require('path');

shell.openItem(path.join(__dirname, 'test.docx'));
```

According to the docs the `shell` module should be available in both the main/browser and renderer processes.

> Note: **Electron 9.0.0** The `shell.openItem` API has been replaced with an asynchronous `shell.openPath` API. [shell.openPath docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenpathpath)

Comment: Can we get a closed signal ? Is there a call back where I would know application was closed ?

Comment: @django No, this is a fire and forget sort of thing. If you want to detect if an external application has closed you'll need to spawn it using [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Comment: @VadimMacagon I have been trying ```ls.on('close'``` event but it gets fired as soon as ms word is opened. Can you please post example or should i create another question for it ?

Comment: Is it possible to show apps/softwares that can open the file, instead of opening it in default app. Example svg file opens in browser by default. I want to let the user choose another app like notepad or other code editor etc. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Adding here the snippet for newer electron versions (9+) *and* imports:

```js
import { shell } from 'electron';
import path from 'path';

shell.openPath(path.join(__dirname, 'test.docx'));
```