# fs.open does not open desired file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just a beginner to nodejs and I came across the fs module. I tried to write a few lines of code.

```
var fs = require('fs'); 

// Open file demo.txt in read mode 
fs.open('/users/Upwn/desktop/ashok_pant.txt', 'r+', function (err, f) { 
  if(err) throw err; 
   console.log('Opened!'); 
});
```

The output was "Opened!" but nothing was opened from my local file system. What may be wrong with this?

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Ifaruki I think he expects the file to open on his operating system, as if you would have double clicked it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902347/open-a-file-with-default-program-in-node-webkit/29917107#29917107

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open the file using the default OS application linked to the filetype, the following answer from [Philipp Kief](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891139/1487756) might be what you're looking for.

> You can use the [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) module:
>
> ```
> npm install --save open
> ```
>
> and then call it in your Node.js file:
>
> ```js
> const open = require('open');
> open('my-file.txt');
> ```
>
> This module already contains the logic to detect the operating system and it runs the > default program that is associated to this file type by your system.

--- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891139/1487756

Comment: But why did not the code I used work?  In the official documentation and also in w3schools it is given as I have written.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read file content, please use readFileSync.
Following is my code that I used before.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');
let content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'products.json')))
for (let line in content) {
    // do something
}
```