# How to get the system information in Electron?

Tags: system, electron

I need to get the system info on the multi platforms in `Electron`. How to get the system information in `Electron`?

Comment: Better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683895/how-do-i-determine-the-current-operating-system-with-node-js

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out this page https://nodejs.org/api/os.html. It is nodejs documentation, but since electron and node are very much the same thing it will work.

```
var os = require('os');
```

is what you are looking for though.