# Node / Javascript import different modules based on target platform?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browserify

I would like to know what methods are available to specify which modules should my app import based on a target platform. I would like to import different implementations  for the same interface in typescript for a browser and for a nodejs.

We have something like

```
#ifdef windows
#include "windowsimplementation.h"
#endif
```

In c++

How could i achieve something similar using typescript node and browserify?

Comment: Possibly without writing if statements in the code and avoiding the node implementation to be exposed in the browserify bundle.

Answer (score 1):

> which modules should my app import based on a target platform

Use the `browser` property in `package.json`.

## More

- Docs https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec

Recommend creating a `node` implementation as default and point `types` to the definitions generated from that. More on types : https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-create-high-quality-npm-packages-using-typescript

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs, you can do it the following way, as per this post: [How do I determine the current operating system with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683895/how-do-i-determine-the-current-operating-system-with-node-js)

```js
// in Nodejs
// possible values for process.platform 'darwin', 'freebsd', 'linux', 'sunos' or 'win32'
var moduleString = {
  'win32': 'windows-node-module',
  'darwin': 'darwin-node-module',
  // ... and so on
}

var module = require(moduleString[process.platform]);
```

In the browser, you can check the os through the `navigator` object:

```js
// in Browser
// possible values windows, mac, linux
var moduleString = {
  'win': 'windows-browser-module',
  'mac': 'mac-browser-module',
  'linux': 'linux-browser-module',
}

function getOS(){
  return navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1 ? 'win' : 
    (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) ? 'mac' : 'linux'; 
}

var module = require(moduleString[getOS()]);
```

Comment: "Possibly without writing if statements in the code " since i am using typescript.

Comment: Browser and nodejs in nodejs i have shared code base that i should include and use different libraries.

Comment: See my updated answer that includes both browser and nodejs