# Define a task property as one that can change per platform

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I am developing a VSCode extension that [provide tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider), how can I specify that a property can change per platform, for example on "shell" task we can have this `tasks.json`:

```json
"tasks": [
{
    "type": "shell",
    "windows": { "command": "wndCmd.exe" },
    "linux": { "command": "lnxCmd" },
    "osx": { "command": "osxCmd" }
}]
```

but for mine it is not possible.

From the sample on documentation, it is not possible create a task like:

```json
"tasks": [
{
    "type": "rake",
    "task": "some",
    "windows": { "file": "winFile" },
    "linux": { "file": "linuxFile" },
    "osx": { "file": "osxFile" }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it by hand:

```json
"taskDefinitions": [
    {
        "type": "rake",
        "required": [
            "task"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "task": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The Rake task to customize"
            },
            "file": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The Rake file that provides the task. Can be omitted."
            },
            "windows: {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "file": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "..."
                    }
                }
            },
            "linux: {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "file": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "..."
                    }
                }
            },
            "osx: {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "file": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that does what you think it does. These are just the properties that "identify" a generated task, they can't be configured by users. See also that issue I linked earlier.

Comment: this code is tested, and work as expected https://github.com/APerricone/harbourCodeExtension/blob/636fc8ad86cd5d4e6e80d8d46bf401a849466786/client/package.json#L438

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a reason why you would need to do that for dynamically generated tasks, that only makes sense for declarative / static task declarations.

Just generate the version of the task that's appropriate for the *current* OS. You can check `process.platform` for that, see also:

- [How do I determine the current operating system with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683895/how-do-i-determine-the-current-operating-system-with-node-js/8684009).

Comment: My task is a wrapper for an external build system, so I want allow the user set different options for different platform, It is not so extraterrestrial...

Comment: There's no such thing as "setting options" for generated tasks. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58836

Comment: thinking about It I understand that I can simply do it by hand...